Powershell: I'm getting an error when moving files that were just downloaded from the internet to a specif folder
After a lot of trial and error, I've got a script with subs to work that automatically downloads multiple PDFs from a specific website. These files are saved directly to my Downloads folder. A specific folder is created in Downloads that relates to the group of files downloaded. The final step is to automatically move all these recently downloaded files directly into this specific folder. The process looks to be working, but I'm still getting this error that I can't figure out.
Here is the error:
"

Move-Item : The parameter is incorrect.

At D:\JeffR\Desktop\Binders\Powershell\MoveDownloads.ps1:24 char:5


Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $DestinationPath -For ...


CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\jeffr\downloads\4871-8428:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand



"
Here is the script section for that error:
Script causing error
Again, the process works. So the obvious question is, why am I getting this error?
Thank you for your professional eyes and support.

Was Script run with user JEFFR (or admin)?  Where was the original downloaded files located?

First: don't use images to post code. Second: we need more code, specificall we need how $PODownload and $recentDownloads were valorized

Within this script: $PSODownload =Join-Path $Downloads $PSO. $Downloads is my Downloads folder. $PSO is pulled from excel sheet 1 cell A1. This is successful. This folder is then created successfully as I can see it there prior to the process of moving the downloaded files to this folder. $RecentDownloads is a Get-ChildItem process that selects files in $Downloads where the $_.LastWriteTime -gt 1.25 minutes.

Again, please, this process works perfectly. All files are moved successfully. But this error still appears.
